# Error when building Primefaces from source

Tags: primefaces

I get the following error when building Primefaces from source:

> GPG Passphrase: *
>   *[DEBUG] Generating signature for C:\primefaces\target\primefaces-6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar gpg: WARNING:
>   "--no-use-agent" is an obsolete option - it has no effect gpg: no
>   default secret key: Sem chave secreta gpg: signing failed: Sem chave
>   secreta [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time:  05:32 min [INFO] Finished at:
>   2018-11-09T11:21:03-02:00 [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.4:sig n (sign-artifacts)
>   on project primefaces: Exit code: 2 -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal o rg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.4:sign
>   (sign-artifacts) on project pr imefaces: Exit code: 2
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja va:215)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja va:156)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja va:148)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
>   ( LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
>   ( LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreaded
>   Builder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleSt arter.java:128)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.jav a:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessor Impl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
>   (Launche r.java:289)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:2 29)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
>   (Launc her.java:415)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356 ) Caused by:
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Exit code: 2
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.gpg.GpgSigner.generateSignatureForArtifact
>   (GpgSi gner.java:254)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.gpg.GpgSignAttachedMojo.execute (GpgSignAttachedM ojo.java:146)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBui ldPluginManager.java:137)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja va:210)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja va:156)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja va:148)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
>   ( LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
>   ( LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreaded
>   Builder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleSt arter.java:128)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.jav a:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessor Impl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
>   (Launche r.java:289)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:2 29)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
>   (Launc her.java:415)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356 ) [ERROR] [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information
>   about the errors and possible solutions, please rea d the following
>   articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
>   xception

GPG asks for a Passphrase, I don't know what to input there and why it is important, I tried leaving it blank or typing anything... little after that the error above occurs but I don't know if it's related to the password or not.

Why the error occurs and how do I proceed to fix it or find the cause? The error stack seems a little too criptic to me.

I'm building the JAR on Windows, with a clean install of Maven and GPG. Does this problem occur because I have no key-pair in GPG/Kleopatra?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're activating `release` profile, [see here](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/9b75ddf1d3a49511362ab3ef9bba482074c96bd3/pom.xml#L732) because gpg-maven plugin is only declared on this profile, [see here](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/9b75ddf1d3a49511362ab3ef9bba482074c96bd3/pom.xml#L832). Just run `mvn clean install` and you should be ok.

Comment: Perfect. The release profile acts to sign the Jar using GPG then. Thanks for the quick answer.